# Multiple IBOutlets to another VC

Tags: ios, swift, iboutletcollection

I'm using IBOutlet Collection where all the buttons will pop another VC, how do I link multiple button to the same VC?
[image: TeamSelection]

[[image: PlayerSelection[2]]

I've tried ctrl and drag selected buttons to the new VC but only one button connects

Comment: You might be better off using a table or collection view controller. While you can put and use a button in each cell, implementing didSelectRowAtIndexPath is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an `IBAction` in your code (dragging from one of the buttons to your code) and then inside that function call                     `self?.present(toVC, animated: true, completion: nil)` (fill in what you need)
once you've done that, just drag from the dot (next to the function) to your buttons.

Comment: oops, didn't see the answer from Matusalem, this basically same thing explained differently, mine works better if you buttons already exist tho (which I think is the case here :p)

Comment: I have IBAction but adding the code throws an error
Cannot convert value type 'HomeTeamSelectionVC.type to expected argument type'UIViewController"

Comment: //IBActions Collection for Player Names
    @IBAction func playerSelectionAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let senderINT = sender.tag
        
        let selectedBtn = self.view.viewWithTag(senderINT) as! UIButton
        
        selectedBtn.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        
         self.present(HomeTeamSelectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        print(sender)
        
    }

Comment: Keep in mind that Apple strongly discourages you to use viewWithTag (they said this during a WWDC keynote). I would advise you to try and create a generic segue (ctrl + drag from the yellow icon on the top of the viewcontroller to the other viewcontroller), give that segue an identifier (attributes inspector) and then call 
`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierName", sender: self)`